# Can a Gloom Blade be enchanted, and if so, what would its base enchantment level be?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

I've been working on my two-weapon fighting Rogue, and I just got a set of [Gloom Blades](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/gloom-blade).

I'm wondering: can they be enchanted, and if so, what base enchantment level would I count the blade as? A +1 because of the masterwork status in bright light, or a +2 due to the enchantment that only works in darkness?

Comment: Hi Michael, and welcome to the site! Check our [tour] if you haven't already, and when you reach 20 rep, you'll be able to join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=rpg.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Can you just sell it and get a quality weapon instead? That thing sucks.

Answer (score 4):

## The rules say you can

[Adding New Abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Adding-New-Abilities):

> Fortunately, it is possible to enhance or build upon an existing magic item.

## The cost is based on what the new item would cost

> The cost to add additional abilities to an item is the same as if the item was not magical, less the value of the original item.

## Absolutely no guidance on what the new item would cost for improved specific items

There just isn't. We have no idea how much of the *gloom blade*'s cost derives from plus-equivalent enhancements, and how much is flat cost. Is a *+1 gloom blade* a +2-equivalent, or a +1-equivalent with a flat-cost special property? The rules don't even give a hint.

All magic weapons are supposed to have at least a +1 enhancement bonus before getting any special ability. The default *gloom blade* doesn't. That awkward exception makes it harder to guess how this should go.

The cost of the item is also less than useful: it doesn't match the cost of a *+1 short sword*, so it's not *just* a +1-equivalent. A flat cost must be involved. But since it's more expensive than a *+1 sorry sword*, is that just a large flat cost, or a +1 *and* a small flat cost?

We just don't know.

## Luckily, it doesn't really matter...

Because you *really* don't want to put more magic on this item without talking to your DM and agreeing on a houserule anyway. In bright light, it losses *all magic properties*. By the rules, that would include any you add. That is such a massive drawback that the best way to use these items is to sell them, unless you have like permanent *deeper darkness* and can see through it or something.

If your DM houserules that the loss only applies to the magic on the weapon already, not any that you add on, that's a different situation. As your DM, I probably would do that, but then rule that the, uh, *gloom* property is a +1-equivalent, which makes adding more things cost more.

Comment: I can't tell if *+1 sorry sword* is typo or commentary. Well played.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.
The cost would be the cost of the new item minus the cost for the Gloom Blades.

> The cost to add additional abilities to an item is the same as if the
>   item was not magical, less the value of the original item. Thus, a +1
>   longsword can be made into a +2 vorpal longsword, with the cost to
>   create it being equal to that of a +2 vorpal sword minus the cost of a
>   +1 longsword.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Adding-New-Abilities

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. What would the new item cost in this case? What does a *+1 gloom blade* cost, so that you can subtract the cost of the regular *gloom blade* from it?

Answer (score 1):

So we know from the link you provided that a normal Gloom Blade costs 8810gp. And from the [Estimating Magic Items Gold Piece Value Table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#Table-Estimating-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values) we know that Magic Weapons cost is Enhancement Bonus squared * 2000 + the cost of a Masterwork weapon (It doesn't have anything about granting feats, so I'm ignoring the fact it occasionally grants one). A MW short sword is 310gp, leaving us 8500gp for the enchanting of the sword, which ends up giving you a bonus of just over +2.

Personally I agree with KRyan, unless you can get someway of always being in supernatural darkness this is just a bad weapon and I would 'upgrade' them by selling them and buying something that always gives you bonuses.